# Reading through a csv file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file `Books.txt` which contains the names of books and the people who have borrowed it . BOOKXXXX is the name of the book and XXXX are digits. Here is an example.

```
BOOK2592,1,2,3,4,5,22
BOOK1234,3,4,5
BOOK0999,4,5,6,7
BOOK0666,10,33,4,5
BOOK2222,1,3,4,5,6,7,88,98,3
```

With this file I need to find out if a given account Number has borrowed the book.

I was not able to think of any solution because I was wondering how to find out the number of times the book was borrowed?

Comment: Why not just grep the file ? `grep book1234 books.txt | grep account` ? It will output the line that contains both of those values.

Comment: Did think of that, but I can never know what the car number is. But now I think I get how to do this. I could get the book number by simply using `cut` and then grep it . . hmm thank you :D Hope this solves it :$

Comment: A more realistic text example could help. I don't know what you mean by 'car number'. Alternatively you could use `awk` to do the cutting if you just need the last field.

Comment: @Lawrence I ment the book number :( sorry got distracted :$

Comment: It is common for booknames (assuming you mean titles) to have newlines in them, how do you put those in the `.txt` file? Do you doublequote the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **really** **several** **independent** requests in the original question, but answering the "which book has account borrowed" with awk could look like this:

```
cat book.sh 
#!/bin/bash
awk -F"," -v acc=$1 '
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ acc ){
      print $1
    }
  }
}' Books.txt
```

Which gives us output like:

```
$ ./book.sh 4
BOOK1234
BOOK0999
```

Comment: What is `NF` ? :)

Comment: NF is an awk internal variable, number of field. All up, what we did was define , as field separator, iterate over all fields greater one (your book title), and check whether they match the account number you passed on the command-line.  In awk this is commonly done by assigning a value to a variable name with the **-v ** option.

Comment: doest actually print the required output. It prints the same book multiple times :/

Comment: Not on my system with your sample input.

Comment: `BOOK2592,1,2,3,4,5,22
BOOK1234,3,4,5
BOOK0999,4,5,6,7
BOOK0666,10,33,4,5
BOOK2222,1,3,4,5,6,7,88,98,3`

Try that as the sample file :)

Comment: You just changed the spec on the fly ... that obviously won't work. Which is the correct format?  This isn't CSV, this is, ummm, something else :D

Comment: let me change the question :) The formatting is messed up on the comments

Comment: Are you SURE you invoked the script with the account number you're looking for?

Comment: Yes :)
`accountNum=$1
awk -F"," -v acc=$1 ' 
{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
{
  if( $i -eq accountNum )
  {
 print $1
  }
}
}' Book.txt`

Comment: Read my comments above. awk, in your invocation, doesn't know what accountNum is, so ANYTHING matches, which is why you get every book several times (once per account).

Comment: I missed that part, I have no idea why :/ But this is the best solution :) Vote up for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl is an excellent text processing language. Its syntax can be ... surprising, but its data structures are extremely flexible:

```
perl -F, -lane '
    $book = shift @F; 
    $books{$book} = [@F]; 
    push @{$users{$_}}, $book for @F; 
} 
END {
    $book="BOOK1234"; 
    printf "book %s has been borrowed %d times, by users %s\n", 
               $book, 
               scalar(@{$books{$book}}), 
               join(",",@{$books{$book}}); 
    $user="1"; 
    printf "user %s has borrowed %d books, %s\n", 
               $user, 
               scalar(@{$users{$user}}), 
               join(",",@{$users{$user}})
' Books.txt
```

```
book BOOK1234 has been borrowed 4 times, by users 1,2,3,4
user 1 has borrowed 2 books, BOOK1234,BOOK2334
```

Comment: Hey @glenn I am sorry but I am looking for a Shell Script solution only :) I will get into pearl soon :)

Comment: Why is that? Calling perl from a shell script is exactly the same as calling awk or grep or cut or ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options of doing this

1. You could grep the file for the book number and then grep for the account

   `# grep account books.txt | cut -d "," -f1`

   which outputs this

   `BOOK0999`
2. Or you could use awk to filter out what you need
   `awk -F ',' '/9/ { print $1} ' books.txt`

   which outputs this
   `BOOK0999`

If you wanted a script, you could do it this way

```
#!/bin/bash
acct=$1
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $1 ]]; then
            echo $line | cut -d "," -f1
    fi
done < books.txt
```

and run the script with `./script acctno`

Comment: Here is what I have : 
`while read -r LINE ; do
bookNum=$(echo $LINE | cut -d "," -f1)
check=$(echo $LINE | grep $bookNum | grep -c $accountNum)
echo "The account has borrowed the book $bookNum"
done < Books.txt`

Comment: Nice work ! So are you going to enter the booknum in the script ?

Comment: actually the solution failed :( :"(

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding exactly what you need... Do you need a script that you enter in an account number, and a book number, and it will tell you if its borrowed it ?

Comment: Yes. : ) if I put in an account number, the it should list all the books borrowed by that account : )

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: What is `=~` ? Sorry using the app. I don't know if my code is highlighted : /

Comment: =~ is a regex compare. In this case, I'm just using it to match the account number that you give on the command line.